# Google Sheets parser for the cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I got a string in the cell "D1-D4, D8-D11"

Need it calc sum of elements "D1, D2, D3, D4, D8, D9, D10, D11"

Output - "8"

I can calc sum of "D1, D2,...D11"
but I need the parser for range "D1-D4"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: =LEN(E75)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E75;",";))+1

Comment: but this formula only counts elements between commas and displays the sum = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution:
=sum(ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1; ",")); "-.(\d+)")+1-REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1; ",")); "\d+");1)))

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(SPLIT(REPT("×"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ",")), "\d+"), NETWORKDAYS(
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ",")), "\d+"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ",")), "-.(\d+)"))+1), "×"))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(SPLIT(REPT("×"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ",")), "\d+"), NETWORKDAYS(
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ",")), "\d+"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ",")), "-.(\d+)"))+1), "×"), "")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I did not precisely formulate the question.
"D1-D4, D8-D11" - single cell text in text in text format.

I'm looking for a summation solution in a cell, not a summation of cells.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18t2uLowNZcS_7j5Zx_6y7KF5y4B0wpPWSQb3nosxKz4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: but with other values, the formula does not calculate correctly